# declare a variadic function using type alias

Tags: c++

I have a class that doesn't get variadic template parameter types directly.
Instead, it gets a type of class that gets variadic template parameters.
Below is a simplified example.

```
template<typename Foo> struct bar;
template<typename Derived, typename F> struct fooBase;


template<typename Derived, typename R, typename ...Args>
struct fooBase<Derived, R(Args...)> {
  using function_type = R(Args...);

  void func(Args&&... args) {
    b->func2(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  
  void set(bar<Derived>* bp) {
      b = bp;
  }

  bar<Derived>* b;
};

struct foo : public fooBase<foo, void(int)> {};

template<typename Foo> 
struct bar {
  using function_type = typename Foo::function_type;

  void func2(/** what here? */) {

  }
};


foo f;
bar<foo> b;
f.set(&b);
f.func(3);
```

Is there a way to solve it inside `bar` without declaring a parent class or extra template parameters?

Comment: If by "solving it" you mean get the  `Args...` pack from foo? You can use `struct bar<foo<R(Args...)>> { ... }`

Comment: @super Actually, it's more complicated. I've edited the post. My question is can I declare a function with `function_type`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288396/c-11-templates-alias-for-a-parameter-pack

Comment: What's the point of `fooBase`? If you remove it you can do just what I said in the comment. Here you can make `void(int)` part of `foo`s signgnature and do the same.

Comment: @super This is just a minimal reproducible example... Actual code has meanings and other complicated things.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is can I declare a function with `function_type`

You can write the following outside `struct bar`:

```
Foo::function_type func;
```

This is a forward declaration of a function named `func2` that has to be defined elsewhere, so that doesn't solve the problem. You also cannot write this inside `struct bar`, due to [this reason](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#spec-7) that StoryTeller mentioned. What you can also write is:

```
Foo::function_type *func;
```

Now you have declared a function pointer. You can have it point to a real function. For example:

```
func = [](int x){ std::cout << x << '\n'; };
```

You can also declare this function pointer inside `struct bar`, and if you can use C++17 or later, you should make it `static constexpr`.
The other trick is that you want a function that takes a parameter pack. Unfortunately, you can't create a type alias for a parameter pack directly. However, you can write:

```
template<typename Foo>
struct bar {
    using function_type = typename Foo::function_type;
    /* static constexpr */ function_type *func2 = [](auto... params) {
        ...
    };
};
```

Because the generic lambda is assigned to the function pointer `func2` which has a concrete type, `func2()` now always takes exactly the same parameters as `function_type`. However, as super mentioned, this only works for lambda functions that do not have any captures, as otherwise the lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer.

However, you don't need to declare a function pointer and assing a lambda in this case, you can just define a normal function that takes a parameter pack:

```
template<typename Foo>
struct bar {
    template<typename ...Params>
    void func2(Params&&... params) {
        std::cout << "Parameters:\n";
        ((std::cout << params << '\n'), ...);
    };

    /* Or with C++20 you can simplify this to:
    void func2(auto&&... params) {
        ...
    } */
};
```

The right version of `func2()` will be called by `fooBase`. The only possible issue with this is that someone else can call `func2` with a different set of arguments than intended. This can be solved with SFINAE or C++20 [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts). For example, using concepts:

```
template<typename Foo>
struct bar {
    using function_type = typename Foo::function_type;

    template<typename ...Params>
    void func2(Params&&... params)
    requires std::invocable<function_type, Params...>
    {
        std::cout << "Parameters:\n";
        ((std::cout << params << '\n'), ...);
    };
};
```

The above is also not perfect, for example the following code:

```
foo f;
bar<foo> b;
f.set(&b);
f.func(3.14);
b.func2(3.14);
```

Will print out `3` and `3.14` respectively.

Comment: You can't write `foo::function_type func` - https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#spec-7

Comment: Also, the lambda trick won't work. You can't assign a generic lambda to a function pointer. It doesn't support the conversion.

Comment: You are right about `foo::function_type func` inside `struct bar`, but the lambda trick does work: https://godbolt.org/z/W7KjKs5j7

Comment: @G.Sliepen Only works for lambdas that does not  capture. So it's a limited trick.

Comment: Mmm... indeed. I've never seen or done that myself. TIL. Useful little trick.